# Azure AD B2C Users - Enable button appears in user's authentication method

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have a custom policy where a B2C user can setup their phone for MFA if they have not setup one yet.
After they have added the number thru that policy, we can see that number added in Azure as shown below.

[image]

However, this number is not available yet in MS Graph API.
We need to manually click "Enable" to make it available in MS Graph API.

As per this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-sms-signin)(shown below), there will be "Enable" button if the user has already registered to MFA where they have phone number associated to their account.

[image]

Upon checking, the user has been disabled for Azure MFA as shown in the sample below.

[image]

May we know if you have ideas about this why "Enable" button appeared and if there's a way we can automate clicking "Enable" button to have the number available in MS Graph.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Using Microsoft Graph REST API beta to you can  [enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-enablesmssignin?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) or [disable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/phoneauthenticationmethod-disablesmssignin?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) SMS-based sign-in. Please go through the documentation and let us know if any need any help.

Comment: Yeah I already tried this one but the "Enable" button still appears. Thank you for the response.